# Why doesn't this Views 3 contextual filter work?

Tags: 7, views

I have expanded the article content type to include a few more fields and want to display an article node as a page.  Each article node (content) I give an alias with the following pattern: press-releases/[name-of-article]

I've set up A "Press Releases" view which has three displays.  Two of the displays are block displays and these work perfectly. I also want to make a page display with this view, and that's where I'm running in to problems. I want this view to be active for any node (content) that has the url press-releases/[name-of-article] and so I set up the view like this:

[image: View - Page Display]

And the Contextual Filter has these settings for the Node ID:

[image: NID settings]

But when I visit any press-releases/[name-of-article] it's like the Contextual Filter is completely being ignored and I just get the node spit out all the default fields as determined by the content type, and not according to the View's Page display. Why is this, and how can it be corrected?

Comment: If you are not getting an answer soon I'd post the exported view instead of screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to play nicely with other modules, views will not override any aliases that point to something already. You're trying to make a view show up on an alias that is already pointing to a standard drupal full page node. This simply will not work.

Options:

1. Stop giving aliases to press release nodes so they are only available at `node/nid`
2. Use a different path for your view so it doesn't conflict with your nodes
3. Use Panels to override your full node page and show that view

**Some other things to consider**
A view is really useful for display a list of things, you should probably consider not using it as a node page in this way. You can get a lot of control over your page layout using the standard display tools Drupal 7 gives you.

Using `Content: Nid` as a contextual filter will not recognize a url in the form of `press-releases/name-of-article`. You would need to use `Content: Title`. You also don't need to specify the raw url value as a default value or add `%` in your view path. The order in which the contextual filters are configured are the order in which they are pulled from the URL.

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking for a solution to this all day yesterday.  But could you clarify what you mean by this: "You also don't need to specify the raw url value as a default value or add % in your view path. The order in which the contextual filters are configured are the order in which they are pulled from the URL."

Comment: And how would one implement Option 2 you outlined above?

Comment: The views path doesn't need the `%` placeholder for contextual filters to work. To do #2 set the path of the page to `press-release` or anything other than `press-releases`. In your `Content: Title` contextual filter you should set the `When the filter value is NOT in the URL` to `Show "Page not found"` since this makes the most sense in this case. You should also expand `more` and make sure `Transform spaces to dashes in URL` is checked.

Comment: I did what you said for number two but it won't return anything but "page not found".  When I go to something like press-release/debra-smith-named-vp-business-development, it just returns "page not found".

Comment: Did you delete the `Content: Nid` contextual filter?

Comment: Yes.  Any ideas?  If I'm being too annoying I can achieve the same visual results by adding extra content types and editing existing ones.  But the working View would make the process a lot less manual for future maintenance.

Comment: @rocketeerbkw 'Transform spaces to dashes in URL' does not seem to work. I have a simple view to filter views by a location. The location field wasn't pulled from taxonomy but rather just a simple select box. So when mysite.com/testviewpage/abu+dhabi it's page not found. I tried %20 I even tried the other option to use '+' sign to allow multiple values to no avail. I tried changing the select value to include abu-dhabi instead of with a space. My views path does not contain any % identifiers on it. Contextual filter is set for location field with display all  results if nothing found...